# Vue loaded twice with Webpack-compiled library

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

I have TypeScript library of Vue components which is compiled to a single JS file with Webpack. The TypeScript project that consumes that library also depends on Vue. When running the app, I can see that two instances of vue are loaded, one included in the library bundle (`/node_modules/my-lib/dist/index.js`) and the one from the project's node_modules (`/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js`).

webpack.config.js of the library:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: "fsaa-util",
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        umdNamedDefine: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    allowTsInNodeModules: true,
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.vue', '.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', 'css'],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        },
        modules: ["src", "node_modules"]
    },
};
```

webpack.config.js of the consumer project:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    allowTsInNodeModules: true,
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/],
                    compiler: 'ttypescript'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.vue', '.wasm', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', 'css'],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        },
        modules: ["src", "node_modules"]
    }
};
```

How vue is imported in both the library and consumer project:

```
import Vue from "vue";
```

As suggested elsewhere, I also tried to use:

```
externals: {
    vue: 'vue',
},
```

in the webpack.config.js of the library, but instead I both get `vue.runtime.esm.js` and `vue.esm.js` loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it turned out I was importing Vue into my components in two ways:

```
import Vue from "vue";
```

and

```
import Vue from "Vue";
```

The PascalCase in the "Vue" caused the error, all other modules imported "vue". This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm not using "Vue" in imports.

Is there a way to pin point the cause of this issue.  I have been dealing with this issue for 2 years now over multiple projects and I expected someone in either the Vue or Webpack community to address it.  The truth is that there are way to many causes of this issue and none of them seem to be related to my issue.